# About JSON attribute in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have re-edit this question to give more details.

I want to get the tags both in 'results.article.tags' and 'results.tags'. And add a new attribute in 'tags', which name is 'checked'.

'results.article.tags' is something like this:

```
['test','newTag']
```

'results.tags' is:

```
[{"_id":"5319267b99d3402a0b2dd0ba","name":"test","hidden":true},
 {"name":"default","_id":"5319321d112d81101aa93778","__v":0,"hidden":true},
 {"name":"newTag","_id":"d1193772531aa819321d8110","__v":0,"hidden":true}]
```

I want get 'tags' which like:

```
[{"_id":"5319267b99d3402a0b2dd0ba","name":"test","hidden":true,"checked":"checked"},
 {"name":"newTag","_id":"531ebb68a872eccc0f64a0af","__v":0,"hidden":true,"checked":"checked"}]
```

Here's my code:

```
var tags = [{}];
async.each(results.tags, function(tag, callback) {
    if (results.article.tags.indexOf(tag.name) >= 0) {
        tag.checked = 'checked';
        tags.push(tag);
    }
    callback();
}, function() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(tags));
});
```

But i only get this:

```
[{},
 {"_id":"5319267b99d3402a0b2dd0ba","name":"test","hidden":true},
 {"name":"newTag","_id":"531ebb68a872eccc0f64a0af","__v":0,"hidden":true}]
```

The problem is i cant find 'checked' in tags. So i add `console.log(tag)` after `tag.checked = 'checked'`. Then the results became:

```
{ _id: 5319267b99d3402a0b2dd0ba, name: 'test', hidden: true }
{ name: 'newTag',
  _id: 531ebb68a872eccc0f64a0af,
  __v: 0,
  hidden: true }
[{},{"_id":"5319267b99d3402a0b2dd0ba","name":"test","hidden":true},{"name":"newT
 ag","_id":"531ebb68a872eccc0f64a0af","__v":0,"hidden":true}]
```

The results show that `tag.checked = 'checked'` didn't work, which makes me much more confused.

Then i tried `console.log(tag.checked)`. This time `'checked'` returned. So `tag.checked = 'checked'` has worked, but why i cant find 'checked' in JSON data? Is `tag.checked = 'checked'` a wrong way to add atrribute to JSON data?

Comment: Because the tag isn't in the list of article tags? There's not enough information here to help, really.

Comment: @ user: The most likely reason is that the `console.log` shown above doesn't actually get run, but a different one elsewhere in your code does, and the tag *its* outputting doesn't have the `checked` attribute. `console.log` statements have their place, but there's nothing quite like stepping through the code in a debugger to see how it's working and what's going on.

Comment: @Andy: If the tag isn't in the list of article tags, then tags.push(tag) will not run. But actually, tags get the new tag. I have rewrite this question to give more details.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I'm sure there's no other `console.log` in my running code. The result is indeed shown by `console.log(tag)`.